# Symfony - curl return invalid request

Tags: php, json, symfony, curl, response

I am using cashflows documentation with specified url to try to return test request but dump() returns this error..

> "V|99E5BB5DF59|000|V226|Invalid request\n"

or

> The controller must return a response (V|99E5BB5DFC6|000|V226|Invalid request
>   given).

My code..

```
  // jSON URL which should be requested
    $json_url = 'https://secure.cashflows.com/gateway/remote';

    $username = '5949138';  // authentication
    $password = 'Ad368w9XYw';  // authentication

    // jSON String for request
    $json_string ="auth_id=5949138&auth_pass=Ad368w9XYw&card_num=4000000000000002&card_cvv=123&card_ex
                    piry=0116&cust_name=Testing&cust_address=My%20house%0AMy%20street%0AMy%20Town&cust_post
                    code=CB22%205LD&cust_country=GB&cust_ip=123.45.67.89&cust_email=test@test.com&tran_ref=abc123
                    &tran_amount=9.99&tran_currency=GBP&tran_testmode=0&tran_type=sale&tran_class=ecom";

    // Initializing curl
    $ch = curl_init( $json_url );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$username . ':' . $password);  // authentication
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json_string));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');

    // Getting results
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

    return new JsonResponse($result);
```

I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: could it be the lowercase t of Content-Type?

Comment: Tried. It's not.

Comment: I think you are missing some params check their documentation .https://www.cashflows.com/hubfs/support/kb/remote_api_integration_guide.pdf. There is a working exemple with curl

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array to the POSTFIELDS

json_encode it:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($json_string),
```

Als check Content-Type (uppercase T)

Comment: Still the same. And when I try example form documentation, error is the same.